# AWS IP instance change and now Nginx dosent work

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx

I restarted my ec2 instance and got assigned a new IP. Now after that my nginx server dosent respond and load forever. I figure I have to manually change the IP but where do I do this?
I have ran both of these commands but it didnt help.

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo service nginx restart
```

I tried to look at

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

but couldnt find any IP.

Comment: You should read the log file to check error logs. Did you do a curl to localhost/ private IP to test it? Restarting your EC2 will not update your private IP, I guess you are talking about public IP. You can assign EIP and your public IP will not change. You need to check the security group as well.

Comment: How do you access your site? Via public ip or domain? I don't think you need to manually change ip anywhere in nginx..